# Facebook LIKE AppId or PageId

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am having an issue logging a "LIKE" for an application page. It seems that the like is not being inserted into the page_fan table. My concern is that I may be trying to LIKE the application page and not the actual page that contains the application as a tab. I have already written the LIKE code and the like does post to my wall etc. but when I perform the me() query against the page_fan table it does note return my uid.

I have tried the LIKE both within my custom page was well as the global LIKE above all canvas pages on FB page.

**My question is: Should my code logic LIKE the ApplicationId(Canvas/iframe) or the PageId in which the Tab exists? Or I am totally off base with my logic.**

Here is what I have developed and what I have found.

I have created applications that are accessible on the left hand side of a facebook page (tabs). These are canvas or iframe applications that generate a unique AppId when a new application is created.

For example, I am currently adding the AppId of a canvas page as an OG tag in same canvas iframe page.

I then access the following URL and select the page from an existing list that this tab should appear:
www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=111111111111111&display=popup&next=http://facebook.myapp.com/canvaspage.html

I wrote the following code to determine the page_id (for example this returned:222222222222222)

```
//App PageId
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url="'+appURL+'"';     
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
$.each(data['data'], function(index, appPageId) {
    if (appPageId) {
        var appPageId = appPageId['id'];                    
    }
});
});


<!-- Open Graph for the "PAGE" PagId that has a relationship to AppId (id:) below / I have found that this will include a likes variable if GT 0 -->
graph.facebook.com/222222222222222 

{
   "id": "222222222222222",
   "name": "TEST APPLICATION",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/373257_225429330866626_1701496970_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://apps.facebook.com/test-app/",
   "app_id": 111111111111111, // Below ID - also the AppId
   "category": "Website",
   "description": "Test App Description",
   "can_post": true
}


<!-- Open Graph for "APPLICATION"  AppId --->
graph.facebook.com/111111111111111 

{
   "id": "111111111111111",
   "name": "TEST APPLICATION",
   "category": "Lifestyle",
   "subcategory": "Food & Drink",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=111111111111111",
   "canvas_name": "test-app",
   "namespace": "test-app",
   "icon_url": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yT/r/4QVMqOjUhcd.gif",
   "logo_url": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yq/r/IobSBNz4FuT.gif",
   "weekly_active_users": "2",
   "monthly_active_users": "2"
}
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to like the Facebook page, not the app ID.  Remember a facebook page can have many App Id's in it (what facebook calls Page tabs).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am now able to init the application with the app_id, but I am LIKING the page_id and that is now logging in the page_fan. Thanks again.